# Create 100 copies of a dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to create 100 copies of a data set (which has 3 variables) but one of the variables need to be assign randomly (1 through 1000)

I know I can use 100 data statement but I don't want to go down that road!

Let say I have data set A and want to create data set A1 to A100, I used the following code;

```
data A1--A100;
    set A;
    do i=1 to 1000;
    var3=int(ranuni(0) * 1000 + 1);
    output A1--A1000;
    end;
run;
```

but SAS does not generate anything at all

Comment: I'm quite confident it generates errors in your log.

Comment: You may want to look into Proc SurveySelect as well to help with random selection. I'm not sure exactly what you're after so not sure it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, hope it could help;

```
    data want;
      set have;
      do dset=1 to 101;
        rand=ranuni(4011120);
        if dset=1 then real=1; else real=0;
        output;
      end;
    run;

proc sort data=want;
  by dset rand;
run;

data want2;
  set permut;
  if real=0 then rank= mod(_N_,366);
  if real then realrank=rank;
run;

proc sort data=want2;
  by dset dayofyear;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it via any shortcut like that.  You could use the macro language to create the 1000 dataset names and 1000 output statements.

However, more than likely you shouldn't do this.  Instead, have one dataset with a BY variable, and then in whatever you're going to do (MCMC or whatever) use that BY variable with the BY statement.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do byvar=1 to 1000;
    var3 = int(ranuni(7)*1000+1);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Also, don't use ranuni(0).  Always use a positive seed (and save it) so you can replicate your results.

Comment: Thanks,let make it clear;

Create R=100 copies of dataset "A",but let the variable VAR be randomly permuted in each copy.

I read these 2 hint, but it didn't provide code;

best way to do this is as a single dataset where each copy of the original data (with random re-orderings of VAR) is stacked on top of each other. 

A random reordering of a set of numbers can be done by randomly generating a variable (RANUNI function) and sort
by that variable.

Not advisable to generate 100 different datasets and stack them up; the entire final dataset should be generated with only 1 or 2 data steps.